# Reference html tag from template

Tags: html, css, web-deployment

I am wanting to access a div tag from the template and add html underneath that tab for a certain page for my website. So assuming that this was my script

```
<!-- Page Content --> 
<div class="span8 page-content" id="page-content">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>  
<!-- /Page Content -->       
<!-- Right Rail -->
<div class="span4 right-rail" id="right-rail">
    <div class="first-col">
    </div>
    <div class="second-col">
    </div>
</div>
<!-- /Right Rail -->
```

is there anyway I could access

```
<div class="span8 page-content" id="page-content">
```

from another script and add html underneath it? I need that part of the template to stay the same except for on this page. So the final script would be something akin to

```
<div class="span8 page-content" id="page-content">
    <div> 
        <div>
        </div>
    </div
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jquery to append HTML to the DOM.
Or 
Use Javascript to find the element by id and add to it.
document.getElementByid ect